# Javascript Newb's Uncaught ReferenceError: Variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the baby-steps for a millwork calculator as my first javascript project.  I think my problem is what order to place the elements in.  I have :

A) a form that only takes numbers,

B) a Submit button that regurgitates those numbers,

C) 2 objects with properties that are supposed to be calculated based on numbers entered on the form.

Why can;t the browser find the objects' properties?  I put at the very top of the page, at the very end, and a few places in between.  Right now they're after all the used variables are read by the submit button, but before they are used in future submit button equations.

I made it as far as the objects.  I guess I really don't have to use them, but I thought it was a good way to start using what I learned in tutorials.

JSFiddle seems to wants to use POST (I think that means PHP) for the submit button to work, but I have it up to see: https://jsfiddle.net/WarOnGravity/26nnzy6e/1/

```
'use strict';

window.onload = function () {

document.getElementById("configForm").addEventListener("submit", barfulateTotal);


function barfulateTotal(barf) {
    barf.preventDefault();

    console.log("You got barf!");

    console.log("Ceiling Height : " + inputCeilingHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCeilingHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputCeilingHeight').innerHTML = ("Ceiling Height : " + inputCeilingHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCeilingHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");

    console.log("Soffit Height:" + inputSoffitHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputSoffitHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputSoffitHeight').innerHTML = ("Soffit Height : " + inputSoffitHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputSoffitHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");



    console.log("Countertop Clearance : " + inputCtopClearance.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopClearance.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputCtopClearance').innerHTML = ("Countertop Clearance : " + inputCtopClearance.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopClearance.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");


    console.log("Countertop Thickness : " + inputCtopThickness.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopThickness.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputCtopThickness').innerHTML = ("Countertop Thickness : " + inputCtopThickness.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopThickness.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");


    console.log("Countertop Elevation : " + inputCtopElevation.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopElevation.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputCtopElevation').innerHTML = ("Countertop Elevation : " + inputCtopElevation.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputCtopElevation.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");




    console.log("Toekick Height : " + inputToekickHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputToekickHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputToekickHeight').innerHTML =("Toekick Height : " + inputToekickHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputToekickHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");

    //Top Reveal
    console.log( "Top Face Reveal : " + inputRevealTop.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealTop.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputRevealTop').innerHTML =("Top Face Reveal : " + inputRevealTop.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealTop.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");

    //Middle Reveal
    console.log( "Middle Face Reveal : " + inputRevealMiddle.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealMiddle.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputRevealMiddle').innerHTML =("Middle Face Reveal : " + inputRevealMiddle.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealMiddle.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");

    //Bottom Reveal
    console.log( "Bottom Face Reveal : " + inputRevealBottom.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealBottom.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputRevealBottom').innerHTML =("Bottom Face Reveal : " + inputRevealBottom.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputRevealBottom.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");




    var boxUpper = {
        height    : inputUpperHeight.value,
        topReveal : inputRevealTop.value,
        midReveal : inputRevealMiddle.value,
        botReveal : inputRevealBottom.value,
        face1     : inputUpperHeight.value - ( inputRevealTop.value + inputRevealBottom.value )
    }

    var boxBase = {
        height    : inputBaseHeight.value,
        topReveal : inputRevealTop.value,
        midReveal : inputRevealMiddle.value,
        botReveal : inputRevealBottom.value,
        toekick   : inputToekickHeight.value,
        face1     : inputBaseHeight.value - ( inputToekickHeight.value + inputRevealTop.value + inputRevealBottom.value )
    }


    console.log("Upper Height:" + inputUpperHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputUpperHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputUpperHeight').innerHTML =("Upper Height : " + inputUpperHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputUpperHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");


     console.log("Upper Face 1 Height:" + boxUpper.face1 + "mm" + " / " + ((boxUpper.face1 / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputUpperFace1').innerHTML =("Upper Face 1 Height : " + boxUpper.face1 + "mm" + " / " + ((boxUpper.face1 / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");


    //Base



    console.log("Base Height:" + inputBaseHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputBaseHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputBaseHeight').innerHTML =("Base Height : " + inputBaseHeight.value + "mm" + " / " + ((inputBaseHeight.value / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");




    console.log("Base Face 1 Height:" + boxBase.face1 + "mm" + " / " + ((boxBase.face1 / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");
        document.getElementById('outputBaseFace1').innerHTML =("Base Face 1 Height : " + boxBase.face1 + "mm" + " / " + ((boxBase.face1 / 25.4).toFixed(3)) + "in");


}   //function barfulateTotal(event)


}
```

I added the "onload" function based on some things I read here, because the submit button wasn't working.  I just keep getting so many wacky sounding errors in Bracket's bug log, I can't guess what's wrong.  Why does it keep telling me console, window, and every single HTML ID is undefined or used before defined?

I thought this would a good, useful calculator project that starts simple.  Any help is appreciated, I'm just looking for advice on which direction to study.

Tom G.

Comment: You do seem to be using variables like `inputCeilingHeitht` without declaring any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, lots to unpack here.

You are trying to attach a named function handler to the button's onclick. but you are defining the function inside of another function Move the function to the global scope (ie not nested inside of the anonymous `window.onload = function () {}` But you are probably going to have problems in JSFiddle because it generally wraps what you define inside of the windows onLoad (ie the functions that look like they would be global still arent. So you could attach the function to the window `window.barfulateTotal = barfulateTotal` and then bind it to the form with `<form id="configForm" onsubmit="return window.barfulateTotal(event)">`

> JSFiddle seems to wants to use POST (I think that means PHP) for the
>   submit button to work

Forms on submit generally go to a server. If you want to prevent that behavior (which it sounds like you do), one easy way is to modify your form to return true or false on submit. We want to return false at the end of your event handler here.

So here's an updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmu66esm/1/

As you'll see, I moved everything out of the onload since jsfiddle already runs in the onload, prevented the form from submitting with a onsubmit handler in the html, gave the submit button an id, bound the event to the submit button's click instead of the form's submit

Comment: I apologize for not being more concise, but I was trying to explain how ignorant I am.  I can't get anything outside the onload function to be recognized, and there is not action by the submit button if it's not within.  ***I don't know why, I'm just say'n.  Does that sound like a symptom that would lead to the objects' properties not being recognized?  I guess I should read 100 calculator tutorials and see if I notice a difference in structure that actually works on my experiment.

Comment: @TomGrossi i edited my post to include a working jsfiddle. let me know if you have any questions and throw an upvote/accept my way if you feel your problem is solved

Comment: It doesn't appear that the posted js file does anything.  The submit button no longer operates at all.

Comment: I just ran it and saw: ```Ceiling Height : 2590mm / 101.969in
Soffit Height : 32mm / 1.260in

Upper Height : 1058mm / 41.654in
Upper Face 1 Height : 1025mm / 40.354in

Base Height : 1054mm / 41.496in
Base Face 1 Height : -9979mm / -392.874in

Countertop Elevation : 914mm / 35.984in
Countertop Clearance : 428mm / 16.850in
Countertop Thickness : 34mm / 1.339in

Top Face Reveal : 3mm / 0.118in
Middle Face Reveal : 4mm / 0.157in
Bottom Face Reveal : 3mm / 0.118in
Toekick Height : 110mm / 4.331in```

Comment: Can you imagine why variables boxBase, boxUpper, and all their properties seem to be undefined?  The 2 equations that are "barfulated" are coming out incorrect.

Comment: lol I have no idea what barfulating is or what you're even trying to calculate but nothing is undefined when I run the jsfiddle that I linked to you. Are you looking at that jsfiddle? Please show me the exact error that you are seeing in your console or what exactly is being mis calculated. As you see from what i posted in the last comment, everything has a value. Why are you suggesting that they are undefined?

Comment: Base Face 1 Height : -9979mm is incorrect.  It equals boxBase.face1  which equals

Comment: I spent alot of time helping you and I fixed your answer. You seem new to this site given you have 1 point. Why do you not upvote and accept my answer? I helped you with all syntax errors but its up to you to fix your logic errors.